# Error when reading properties from yml file in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, yaml, properties-file

My yml file looks like this

```
   template:
        age: 2
        row: 6
        attributes:
          - tagname: tag
            type: string
            value: VALUE
            scopes:
                - one-scope
                - second-scope
```

Reading the same data from a .properties file works!

```
template.age=2
template.row=6
template.attributes[0].tagname=tag
template.attributes[0].type=string
template.attributes[0].value=VALUE
template.attributes[0].scopes=one-scope,second-scope
```

My propertis pojo it's written in kotlin and looks like this:

```
class TemplateProperties {
    @NotNull
    lateinit var age: String
    @NotNull
    lateinit var row: String
    var attributes: List<Attribute> = mutableListOf()
}
```

and Attribute

```
class Attribute {
    @NotNull
    lateinit var tagname: String
    @NotNull
    lateinit var value: String
    @NotNull
    lateinit var type: String
    var scopes: Array<String> = arrayOf()
}
```

The error I get is this

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.List<props.Attribute>]
```